# buddypress registration issue

Tags: wordpress, registration, buddypress

Please suggest me that how can I stop using buddypress registration and profile page.
As, I already do have registration and profile page.
I want to use that only. My earlier registration page ” http://www.ferie.nu/wp-login.php?action=register” which is redirecting to register page of buddy press.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a registration page then choose that page as buddypress register page.

1. Go to dashboard.
2. Under settings menu-> buddypress.
3. Click on "pages" tab in buddypress settings.
4. Under Registration section, Select your registration page from drop down and save it.

With this you might get redirected to your registration page.

Comment: My registration page is inside wp-login.php, the link is given as wp-login.php?action=register, then inside that code it matches for this condition and execute it but right now it's simply throwing the output of register.php of buddy press.